# How to connect Neo4j database to my Apache Camel Karavan application?

Tags: integration, apache-camel-k

I have explored the option for the kamelets and we don't have any source connector sink for the neo4j database.

[https://camel.apache.org/camel-kamelets/4.0.x/index.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

Is there any possibility to perform database operation from the Camel Karavan to the neo4j ?

I tried to establish connection using JDBC sink present in the kamelets, but it is not working for cyper queries.